# Creating a 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of tuples of the form:

[([sentence_1], [sentence_embeding_1]), ([sentence_2], [sentence_embeding_2]),....([sentence_n], [sentence_embeding_n])]

sentence_embeding_n is of dimension 786.

I would like to creat a 2d numpy array of the shape (n, 786), where n is the total number of sentences. The number of sentences are in hundred thousands. Is there a efficient way of creating this 2d array ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import numpy as np

lst = list_of_sentences

array = np.array(lst).reshape(len(lst),786)
```

Comment: Thanks CodeBoi. The code helped a bit. I solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it